# Freezing 'Language Selector' popup in Sitecore 6.4.1 after installing Claytablet CT3 Connector

Tags: sitecore

I am having an issue relating to ClayTablet during post installation on a sitecore project with version 6.4.1 (rev. 120113) whereby hitting the ‘Translation’ button on the ‘Review’ tab will result in a blank ‘Language Selection’ popup box. I am at the step where I am ready to export an item to my Translation provider for translation via the CT3 Connector in XML.

I have performed all the necessary installation and configuration steps to get my languages and regional ISO codes setup under System > Languages, and finally came across this this issue.

I have performed all the following:
1.  Installed the CT3 Sitecore Connector database in the same server where my sitecore databases (core, master and web) are located with my multilingual sitecore solution.
2.  Installed the CT3 Sitecore Connector package via the Package Installation Wizard via the Desktop window
3.  Setup the source.xml and target.xml in my Data/CT3/Accounts folder
4.  Configured the appropriate global parameters to ensure that translation works properly (by default the connector will export this in XML format)
5.  Configured my items with CT3 Sample Workflows attached so that this can be submitted using the ‘Translate’ button that appear in the Workflow ribbon under the ‘Review’ tab.

Please see screenshot below.

[image]

Within the same item, the following workflow fields have been attached to the CT3 Sample Workflow.

[image]

If any of you came across a blank popup such as the above, will someone be able to advise and shed some light on this. Will greatly appreciate any of your help as I have a deadline tomorrow to sort out translation of website.

Comment: Any exceptions being logged?

Comment: Mark - Yes I do a have two to three errors of which have existed before I installed the CT3 Connector.
  

ERROR Exception in UrlAgent (url: /sitecore/service/keepalive.aspx)
Exception: System.Net.WebException
Message: The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.
Source: System
   at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadDataInternal(Uri address,..
ERROR Exception in alarm clock event subscriber.

ERROR Exception: System.UnauthorizedAccessException
Message: Access to the registry key 'Global' is denied.

Comment: Ok.. unfortunately none of these exceptions are related. I don't think I can offer much assistance then, other than I believe this must be related to the CT3 connector. You sure you're not missing some browser settings?  Flash, Silverlight, certain minimum version or such?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my answer from Sitecore Claytablet support. It appears my web.config was missing this one line of code in the controlSources section for some no apparent reason.

[image]

Once putting this line of code in, the language selector popup displayed properly.

Thanks for your help anyway. :)